Stuck on "Welcome Firebase Hosting Setup Complete"
I am stuck on the firebase welcome screen for my React project and can't seem to figure out why. I think the problem might be that I don't have an index.html in my src
and I also have my index.js code if needed:
//index.js

import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';


const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App/>
  </React.StrictMode>
);



I tried firebase deploy on my React project like 5 times and then firebase init to click no on everything but nothing seems to work

On Stack Overflow, please don't show pictures of text and code. Copy the text into the question itself and format it so that it's easy to read, copy, and search. You can edit the question to correct this using the edit link at the bottom.
